# Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '%' in Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm using Java and MySQL to search by name, before I used to connect to Oracle and everything run good, and Now I change to migrate to MYSQL and see error..

MySql:

```
SELECT  CAR.ID AS ID, 
    CAR.NAME AS NAME, 
    CAT.ID AS CATEGORY_ID, 
    CAT.NAME AS CATEGORY_NAME,
    C.ID AS CITY_ID,
    C.NAME AS CITY_NAME,
FROM    CARS CAR,       
    CATEGORY CAT,
    CITY C
WHERE   LOWER(CAR.NAME) LIKE '%'||LOWER(?)||'%' 
    AND CAR.CATEGORY_ID         = CAT.ID  
    AND D.CITY_ID               = C.ID
ORDER BY CAT.NAME, CAR.NAME
```

When deploy and debug to search query, it happened an error:

Log message:

```
SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1114, SQLState: HY000
SqlExceptionHelper - The table 'C:\Windows\TEMP\#sql730_a_47' is full
HibernateUtils - error at HibernateUtils.getListResult: could not extract    ResultSet
SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: HY000
SqlExceptionHelper - Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '%'
SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: 1114, SQLState: HY000
SqlExceptionHelper - The table 'C:\Windows\TEMP\#sql730_a_47' is full
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)||'%'
    AND CAR.CATEGORY_ID         = CAT.ID at line 50
```

How can I fix the problem ? thank so much

Comment: you need to use concat  for concatenation plz remove ||

Comment: how your code loop like?

Comment: As a note:  I removed the Oracle and PL/SQL tags.  The error is a MySQL error, so the code is clearly intended to be MySQL code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes I see, this is my syntax error mysql, I'm testing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was (originally) tagged for both MySQL and Oracle.  The question itself and the error strongly suggest that MySQL is the database (Oracle doesn't produce MySQL errors, for instance).

MySQL does not use `||` for string concatenation.  The correct way to write your query is:

```
SELECT CAR.ID AS ID, CAR.NAME AS NAME, CAT.ID AS CATEGORY_ID, 
       CAT.NAME AS CATEGORY_NAME, C.ID AS CITY_ID, C.NAME AS CITY_NAME,
FROM CARS CAR JOIN      
     CATEGORY CAT
     ON CAR.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ID JOIN
     CITY C
     ON D.CITY_ID = C.ID
WHERE LOWER(CAR.NAME) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(?), '%')
ORDER BY CAT.NAME, CAR.NAME;
```

Also note the correct use of `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
LIKE '%'||LOWER(?)||'%'
```

You can use :

```
"...LIKE LOWER('%"+ str.toLowerCase() +"%')"
```

Or :

```
Query query = "...LIKE LOWER('%?%')";
query.setParameter(1, str.toLowerCase());
```